# In a Razor View's @html.ActionLink, how do we pass the value of a dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown

So what I am trying to do is that I have a database table of Roles, that I want to display in a dropdown list, and send the value to a different controller function. However, when I try to do this, I do not receive the value of the new Role that is selected from my dropdown list, but instead the value that was previously in my Model.
Here is my code for CSHTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineStoreData.Model.User>
<h4>List of Users: </h4>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var user in Model) {
    if (user.Role.RoleName.TrimEnd(' ') == "User")
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => user.Role.RoleName, new SelectList(ViewBag.RoleList)) //Here I need to select a new Role, for example "Admin"
            @Html.ActionLink("Promote", "Promote", new { id = user.UserId, role = user.Role.RoleName }) |  
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = user.UserId })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
}

</table>
```

and this is the code for my Controller

```
public ActionResult ManageUsers()
{
    ViewBag.RoleList = storeDBEntities.Roles.Select(role => role.RoleName).ToList();
    return View(storeDBEntities.Users.ToList());
}

public ActionResult Promote(int id, string role)
{
    //Here I should get  the new role selected in the dropdown list, but I keep getting "User", which is the old role. 
    User toPromUser = storeDBEntities.Users.Find(id);
    Role newRole = storeDBEntities.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoleName == role);
    if(toPromUser != null && newRole != null)
    {
        toPromUser.Role = newRole;
        toPromUser.UserRole = newRole.RoleId;
        storeDBEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers", "Users");
}
```

I am not sure how I should fix this to get the code to perform what is intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you cannot dynamically append the selected value of your dropdown to your action link without JavaScript.

I think a more elegant approach would be to put your drop down and action buttons in a `<form>`. That way the method can also be a `post`, which is a bit more nice in a way, as `get` operations should not manipulate data.

```
<td>
    <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Promote", new { id = user.UserId })">
        @Html.DropDownList("role", new SelectList(ViewBag.RoleList))
        <button type="submit">Promote</button>
        |  
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = user.UserId })
    </form>
</td>
```

Note that the `name` of your drop down list should match the name of the `role` parameter of your controller.

---

When that works, you could then add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to your `Promote` action, to clarify that this method changes something.

For your delete action you could do something similar. Either make a second `<form>` with a different URL, or make it a submit button, too, in the same form, and give the buttons each a `name` and `value`.
The value of the button you clicked on will be sent to the server - note that I changed the form action URL:

```
<td>
    <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Update", new { id = user.UserId })">
        @Html.DropDownList("role", new SelectList(ViewBag.RoleList))
        <button type="submit" name="operation" value="promote">Promote</button>
        | 
        <button type="submit" name="operation" value="delete">Delete</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

And then decide what to do in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(int id, string operation, string role)
{
    ...
```

Lastly, you probably want a confirmation message on the delete action, which can be done so:

```
<button type="submit" name="operation" value="delete" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this user?');">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Hello, 
This worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I would never have thought of using a form as I had mentally saperated a form and a table and had never used them together.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked! The neat thing about MVC is that the controllers don't really care where the parameter values come from, and that you don't have the old limitation of ASPX anymore, where you could only have one form on the page. Cheers!